# How to bridge wired network into a wireless LAN as a single client?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Recently, I've found myself in a bit of a dilemma. I have several wired devices I need to connect to an enterprise type network. Unfortunately, only wireless LAN access is available in this situation. The devices in question are, at this time, limited to a desktop computer, a couple VoIP analog telephone adapters (since there is no landline access anymore), and a laptop connected only intermittently.

I also have a Linksys WRT54G router at my disposal, as well as two 5-port Fast Ethernet switches.

I need to be able to somehow connect all the devices to the main network, wirelessly, though I'd like them physically connected via Ethernet cables from the device. I'd like to make the wired to wireless transition in a central place.

I've already consulted the following SU question: [Bridging wireless network to remote wired devices](https://superuser.com/questions/521655/bridging-wireless-network-to-remote-wired-devices)

While that gave me a good feel for what might need to be done, it doesn't answer all my questions. In this case, I have *no* control over the main wireless network being used, and no ability to control how I connect to it. The connection is not merely an SSID and key either; it entails additional device registration. There are, however, provisions to get devices w/o such capabilities (e.g. Internet of Things appliances) wireless connected to the network. Not sure if I could somehow take advantage of that capability.

I'm wondering what the best way to go about bridging my setup with the main network would be here. Is a "wireless bridge" as mentioned still an option? Can I make use of my WRT54G in some way by connecting that to the wireless network as a "client" and then connect all my devices to one of my Ethernet switches and connect that to the repurposed router?

Currently, I do, in fact, use my WRT54G on "gateway" mode, e.g. as a router (the wireless is disabled as I don't need it). That is, instead of using it as a switch, I use it as a gateway so that internal devices are *not* directly reachable from the outside, and all traffic comes from a single main network IP address as opposed to from unique ones. This setup, however, is completely unrelated; it's on gateway mode in a completely different environment for different reasons. But I'm wondering if perhaps I could continue using this gateway mode to my advantage.

Another thing I was concerned about - I could potentially use the laptop to register with the network but that would not be a permanent part of my local setup, so is there any way to "transfer" this registration to the WRT54G? (e.g. spoofing the MAC address).

Comment: Why.not just get a DD-WRT device (router) and set it up as an AP client.  Thus means your router will act like one so only it needs to be known on the remote.side. If you dont control the WIFI side of the network, it probably means that you need to use another subnet and NAT, limiting network discovery though.

Comment: @davidgo Using another subnet and NAT is fine by my. Devices don't need to be reachable outside my little mini-LAN. I do not control the Wi-Fi side of the network at all, correct. Can you tell me more about DD-WRT and setting it up as an AP client? Is this the same device as the router or in addition to it?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. If you get a router running dd-wrt you can set that router up so that it uses WIFI as a WAN interface. Have a look at https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless